# How to upgrade my Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10, versions

How can I upgrade my Ubuntu version to 13.10. My current Ubuntu version is 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

Open software updater from dash (search) and let it update package lists, If all programs on your computer are up to date it should notify you about the release update.